setup NTP debian
I have a local NTP server that is set up with the correct time for our timezone. I also have a Debian computer with an NTP client configured to sync with the local server.
I tried keeping the wrong timezone on the Debian computer and setting up NTP to sync with the local server. However, the time still reflects the incorrect timezone.
Do I need to set the timezone on the Debian PC as well? I was under the impression that having an NTP server meant that I wouldn't need to set the timezone manually.
Thank you

Does this answer your question? Does NTP daemon set the host timezone?

NTP does not use or affect time zones - internally, the Linux kernel and NTP daemons all use UTC.  Time zones must be set on each system individually.
